# Fit text box to the text in Google Drawings

Tags: google-drawings

I would like to fit every box to the text. Seems like not an option in Format. Is this a missing feature?

Comment: Please check out the [Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs). There you can learn what features are included in Google Drawings. If the feature that you are looking for is not included, send your feedback directly to Google from the Google Drawings Help menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Preferences -> General, you can select "Resize shape to fix text". You can also resize the text box on an individual basis by selecting the text and then selecting a little dialog with three lines that pops up to the left of it.

Answer (score -2):

Rn you could probably just use the image sizer this with the boxes on the corner if you know what I mean. Or if you mean order layering just two finger tap and press order. Ask questions in different places as well